# Filter default_content only for products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, post-content

Is there any way to use `default_content` only for a certain post type, specifically `product` (WooCommerce)?

My code:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'set_default_content', 10, 2 );
function set_default_content( $content, $product ) {
    $content ='content to add to a post']';
    return $content;
}
```

I've tried with `if ( 'product' == get_post_type() )` or even `if ( 'page' == get_post_type() )` to test it but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default_content` is a filter used in the backend. You don't necessarily have anything in the loop so standard functions will probably fail. However, you're given a second argument of type `WP_Post`. You can check its `post_type` easily and work from there.

```
add_filter('default_content', 'WPSE_product_default_content', 10, 2);
function WPSE_product_default_content($post_content, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type !== 'product')
        return $post_content;

    $content ='content to add to a post'
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I actually manged to do it by calling the global variable inside the function. Is it considered a bad way to do it this way? add_filter( 'default_content', 'set_default_content', 10, 2 );
function set_default_content( $content, $post ) {
  global $post_type;
  if ('product' == $post_type) {
    $content ='[block id="2346"]';
    return $content;
 }
}

Comment: Not sure about good / bad practice. But can you trust the global variable? `$post->post_type` will **always** yield what you expect it. I have no idea what might manipulate `global $post_type` or what not